# Volley Not Calling onResponse or onErrorResponse

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a problem in my app i try to get data from a json file from url and i did it using volley

First of all this is what i did in my Oncreate method

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    jsonParce();
```

and this is JsonParce Method

```
private void jsonParce() {


    Log.d("MyApp", "In JsonParce -- "+appbanner);


    String url = "link";
    JsonObjectRequest request= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Log.d("MyApp", "In OnResponse -- "+appbanner);


            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                appbanner =jo.getString("banner");
                appinter = jo.getString("inter");



            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Log.d("MyApp", "Exception -- "+appbanner);

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.d("MyApp", "ERROR -- "+appbanner);

            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Log.d("MyApp", "out --"+appbanner);


    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

and when i did some logs I found out that the app not calling on response or onError methods

and in logs it's not showing any errors the emulator is fully connected to the internet

this is my logs

```
  2019-10-02 15:28:03.281 2677-2677/? I/.ftylopm.nosrt: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-10-02 15:28:03.414 2677-2677/? W/.ftylopm.nosrt: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-10-02 15:28:03.655 2677-2677/com.ftylopm.nosrti I/.ftylopm.nosrt: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-10-02 15:28:04.457 2677-2677/com.ftylopm.nosrti W/.ftylopm.nosrt: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-02 15:28:04.458 2677-2677/com.ftylopm.nosrti W/.ftylopm.nosrt: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-02 15:28:04.550 2677-2677/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/MyApp: In JsonParce -- null
2019-10-02 15:28:04.556 2677-2677/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/MyApp: out --null
2019-10-02 15:28:04.595 2677-2741/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-10-02 15:28:04.608 2677-2677/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-10-02 15:28:04.692 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-02 15:28:04.693 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-02 15:28:04.693 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-10-02 15:28:04.693 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-10-02 15:28:04.694 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-10-02 15:28:04.694 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-10-02 15:28:04.701 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe62856c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-10-02 15:28:04.743 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe62856c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe6283780)
2019-10-02 15:28:04.828 2677-2746/com.ftylopm.nosrti D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe62856c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe6283780)
```

Comment: You should add a Catch (Exception e2) to catch a non-JSON Error.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a retry policy to your request to get a timeout when the server takes to long to respond:

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Also, try your code with a working url such as "https://www.google.com" instead of "link"

Comment: hey thanks for your response i've done that and still the same problem

Comment: same problem still skipping the methods

Comment: Are you connected to internet ? Can you try with a standard StringRequest() of type Request.Method.GET on "https://www.google.com" and post the logs ?